# Изменение формата datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Есть дата в таком формате "2022-03-29T01:12:14+00:00"
как мне ее перевести в такой "23.03.2022 01:12:14".
Пробовал так

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-03-29T01:12:14+00:00", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00').strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')
```

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

я так полагаю эту часть тоже нужно задать форматом "+00:00", но я не нашел и не знаю каким.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Ну вашу дату распарсит `datetime.fromisoformat()` (несмотря на его кривость).

Comment: `strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None` вангую что у вас там переменная и она `None`

Comment: @gil9red да, действительно это я олух) в списке есть значения None и как по иронии первое значение именно такое. Поправил и заработало. Большое спасибо